# Activity with Dialog Theme gets clipped after returning from backgrounded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have a weird behavior where starting an Activity with `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` gets clipped if I background the app and then return to the foreground.  I have observed this behaviour in other situations as well, such as not using AppCompat.

I have created a test app (code below) that demonstrates this issue.  I have also included screenshots to better illustrate the issue.

This doesn't happen on all devices.  Nexus 5 running Android 5.1.0 has this problem.  M appears fine.

### Screen Shots

#### App Launch / Before Backgrounding

[image]

#### Return from backgrounding

[image]

As you can see, the title area is smaller, and you can see some text in the activity below.  If you dismiss the dialog, the missing portion of the dialog will temporarily re-appear and then everything disappears as you'd expect.

### Code

#### `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class));
  }
}
```

#### `DialogActivity.java`

```
public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
  }
}
```

`DialogActivity` is declared in my Manifest as follows

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
          android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"/>
```

#### `activity_dialog.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="400dp"
              android:layout_height="1000dp"
              android:background="@color/dialogColor"
              android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

#### `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas?  I can provide more info if needed!

Thanks :)

### Edit -- Added the main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ben.movingdialog.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding requestWindowFeature() for removing the dialog title ?

Comment: The clipping problem happens whether the dialog has a title or not .. I included the pics with the title as it's easier to see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To overcome this clipping, first remove the title of your activity with adding the following line **before** the **setContentView()**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Then, add a textView to the top of your activity layout to server as the title.

Comment: This has the same issue, part of the layout will still be clipped, there will just be no title

Comment: appended to the main comment